# How to create a copy of VM Ware installation to be used on another computer?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have a VM WARE installation which has multiple files including a big file  with extension .vmdk.

I want to create a copy of this installation so that it can be used at another machine.

How to create a copy?

If I just copy paste all files after installing VMWARE, will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of what files you've described, I believe you're asking if you can move a virtual machine from place to place.

If that's the case, yes you can move VMs from place to place simply by copying the folder containing items like the vmdk, vmx, and etc.

Once the VM has been copied to the new location you'll have to re-register it for the new system to recognize the file.

VMware Workstation/Fusion: New Virtual Machine -> Import an Existing Virtual Machine
VMware ESXi: Browse datastore, select folder, right click the VMX file and select "Add to Inventory"

Comment: I want to copy the installation to another machine. From your answer following is my understanding:
(1)- Install VMware on machine-2 (target machine).
(2)- Copy existing VM files whole folder from machine-1 (source machine) to machine-2.
(3)- Register newly copied files with VMware workstation on machine-2. 

Am I right?